# Uniformly convex implies strictly convex

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

How to prove Uniformly convex implies strictly convex

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? If you cannot start the proof you can look at any book that discusses these concepts.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy.. i seen but there are different definitions are there so im confusing

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\delta > 0$ in the definition of uniform convexity, it follows that
$$\left\|\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}y\right\| < 1$$
whenever $\|x\| = \|y\| = 1$, which is the definition of strict convexity in the special case for $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$. As it turns out, verifying strict convexity for $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ (or indeed, for any one fixed value of $\lambda \in (0, 1)$) is sufficient to prove strict convexity in general.

To prove this, we start by assuming $\lambda \in \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right)$. We have that
$$\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y = 2\lambda\left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}\right) + (1 - 2\lambda)y,$$
hence
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y\| &= \left\|2\lambda\left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}\right) + (1 - 2\lambda)y\right\| \\
&\le 2\lambda\left\|\frac{x}{2} + \frac{y}{2}\right\| + (1 - 2\lambda)\|y\| \\
&< 2\lambda + 1 - 2\lambda = 1.
\end{align*}
If $\lambda \in \left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)$ instead, a similar approach will work. Or, indeed, interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$, and replace $\lambda$ with $1 - \lambda$. So, in any case, we have $\|\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y\| < 1$ for $\lambda \in (0, 1)$.